# Should I be sanitizing user-created strings before input into MongoDB (using the C# driver)?

Tags: c#, string, mongodb, sanitize

Using `MongoCollection<ThingWithString> collection`, should I be wary of calling `collection.Insert(stringythingy)`? If a user-given field in ThingWithString is, eg `";db.dropDatabase();`, am I setting myself up for some misery down the line?

Comment: rule of thumb...always validate the data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: **no**, there's no need for sanitizing user input on entry to MongoDB for the reasons you mentioned. There is no equivalent of "SQL Injection" in MongoDB, because of its binary transfer format (BSON).

No string inside a BSON document can be mistakenly interpreted as code (e.g. `";db.dropDatabase();`), unless you try really hard - for example, if you build your own string representation of the code you want to run and pass that to `db.eval()`, which you should probably never do anyway.

As long as you use the driver's native methods for communicating with Mongo, any data you include in your requests will be mapped by the driver to a valid BSON document before it's sent to the server -- that's the driver's responsibility.

You could, however, decide to sanitize user input as it's going into Mongo for other purposes (e.g. HTML-encode it), but that's totally up to you. Personally, I'd do that on the way out rather than on the way in for a variety of reasons that are outside the scope of this question.